# Android RecyclerView Not working correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have a recycler view in a fragment. When I load it first and send it to a certain position, it works fine.

But when I reload the same fragment with modified date, it always scrolls to the 3 or 4 adapters above where I want it to scroll to. In effect, my scrolled position always comes to the bottom of the screen.

```
mRecy.scrollToPosition(mScrollToPosition);

mRecy.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(mScrollToPosition);
```

I've tried both these methods with the same result. I've also tried using a delay handler to delay the scroll by 200-300ms. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I was using the following lines in the createview function.

```
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(_mActivity);
    mRecy.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

The data was getting refreshed in a private function. So the first time around it was working. Second time around, these lines were getting missed. Just moved these lines inside the get data function and works like a charm.